# Model Binding Issue in Azure Function After Switching to Azure.Storage.Queues

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

I use Azure Functions with Queue triggers in my backend and up to this point, I'd been using the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` package to handle all Azure Storage operations i.e. queues, blobs, etc. With this package, I'd simply send a `MyQueueRequest` object to my queue and everything worked fine.

Because the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` package has been deprecated, I swithched to `Azure.Storage.Queue` and my Azure Function started throwing the following error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'message'.
> System.Private.CoreLib: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it
> contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or
> an illegal character among the padding characters.

I've found this article that suggests that the new library requires `JSON` objects to be encoded in `Base64` (https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2020/10/16/sending-json-with-net-core-queueclient-sendmessageasync/).

Up to this point, I actually never even serialized my `MyQueueRequest` object to `JSON`. The model binder took care of that for me automatically.

Does this mean, going forward, before sending the message to my queue, I need to first serialize `MyQueueRequest` object and then `Base64` encode it and then reverse the process in my Azure Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for this new package you will need to do this.  I ran into the same problem when trying to add POCOs to a queue.  I use similar code to the article you cite.

I use the following code to handle this:

```
await queue.SendMessageAsync(Base64Encode(JsonSerializer.Serialize(myObject)));
```

Where Base64Encode is:

```
    private string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }
```

Be sure it's also UTF-8.  I'm using System.Text.Json for this example, but Newtonsoft would work just as well.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your response!